# MySQL Databases appearing separated from others?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Some of my MySQL databases will show when I click on one (Phpmyadmin) to the left. But then my more recent databases are separated from the other ones. And I can't switch between database windows if I have them open in tables or it will just switch to the last accessed database.

CURRENTLY USING:  2.8.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using version: 3.3.10

In the left part, I have the most recent used, and above, a *combo* (select/dropdown) which allows me to switch...

Otherwise, in the middle part, in the top-left, I have the *name of my server*, and if I clicked on it, I can see my databases in the middle part when I click on *Databases*.

Comment: Yeah I don't see that I'm using  2.8.0.1

Comment: Ok.. I can't test with this specific version...

Maybe, as a workaround, you can open tabs when you choose databases to work on them...

Comment: Have you tested with different browsers? (maybe, it works better with another one)

Comment: Yeah, but when I do that unless I switch databases the tabs will just reload as the last accessed database if I make any transaction

Comment: And yes I've tested it with chrome, firefox, safari, and IE with the same result

Comment: ;o( if you have access to the folder where it's hosted... you can check the config file if there's not a specific setting... or install a [recent version](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php).

Comment: Alright I'll see if I can upgrade thanks.